# Update view with value of new instance

Tags: ios, swift, charts, instance

I am trying to update a chart with new values.  I can create a new instance of the class, but I don't know how to update the view to reflect the value of the new instance.

My chart class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CounterView: UIView {

    let possiblePoints = 100
    let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

    var counter: Int = 20
    @IBInspectable var outlineColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    @IBInspectable var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // 1
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

        // 2
        let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)

        // 3
        let arcWidth: CGFloat = 76

        // 4
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 4
        let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 4

        // 5
        var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)

        // 6
        path.lineWidth = arcWidth
        counterColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()

        //Draw the outline

        //1 - first calculate the difference between the two angles
        //ensuring it is positive
        let angleDifference: CGFloat = 2 * π - startAngle + endAngle

        //then calculate the arc for each single glass
        let arcLengthPerPoint = angleDifference / CGFloat(possiblePoints)

        //then multiply out by the actual glasses drunk
        let outlineEndAngle = arcLengthPerPoint * CGFloat(counter) + startAngle

        //2 - draw the outer arc
        var outlinePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: bounds.width/2 - 2.5,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: outlineEndAngle,
            clockwise: true)

        //3 - draw the inner arc
        outlinePath.addArcWithCenter(center,
            radius: bounds.width/2 - arcWidth + 2.5,
            startAngle: outlineEndAngle,
            endAngle: startAngle,
            clockwise: false)

        //4 - close the path
        outlinePath.closePath()

        outlineColor.setStroke()
        outlinePath.lineWidth = 5.0
        outlinePath.stroke()
    }
}
```

The value of `counter` is `20` by default, but I need to update the UIView to reflect the value of a new instance of `CounterView()`.  The score I am passing in is 50 in the below function:

My ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var chart: CounterView!

func scoreDisplay(score:Double) {
    let counterView = CounterView()
    counterView.counter = Int(score)
    print(counterView.counter)
    chart = counterView
    chart.counter = counterView.counter
    chart.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

This sets the value of `chart.counter` to the proper value of `50` instead of the default value of `20`, but I need to re-draw the chart, and `setNeedsDisplay()` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: have you checked if drawRect of your chart is called?

Comment: how is `CounterView` related to the class which sets the `counter` property?

Comment: drawRect is only called once at the beginning, but isn't called again after I create the new instance.  That's the issue, I don't know how to call it after creating a new instance.

Comment: vadian - I'm not sure what you mean.  `CounterView` is the class in which `counter` is originally defined.  I want to create a new instance of it, and display those changes from my ViewController.